# Manual computation of the predictions in a convolutional neural network

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, cnn, convolutional-neural-network, categorical-data

I am trying to manually compute the predictions of the Keras library for a convolutional neural network. However, I am struggling a lot to match my final result with the ones provided by Keras. I do appreciate it if you could help me with this question.

I have a $r\times c$ tensor that includes categorical values. I apply the one-hot encoding method to convert this tensor to zeros and ones, which results in a $r\times c \times m$ tensor (a multi-channel tensor). I am trying to develop a regressor CNN to predict some quantitative values. The model summary is as follows:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 27, 3, 10)         550       
                                                                 
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 27, 3, 20)         1820      
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, 9, 1, 20)         0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 180)               0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 20)                3620      
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 20)                0         
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 10)                210       
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 11        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 6,211
Trainable params: 6,211
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

- My understanding is that each channel/kernel has a bias that will be added to all of its elements after the convolution. Is that correct?
- For the flattening layer, my understanding is that one should start by flattening the first, channel, then the second channel, and so forth. For each channel, they need to flatten by rows (i.e., start from the first row, then the second row, and so forth). Am I correct?

To fully grasp how a CNN works, I am using the weights determined by the Keras model and computing the prediction manually, and comparing it with the prediction of Keras. However, my manual calculation is too different than the Keras prediction. Would you please look at my code and let me know where I am making a mistake? To reproduce the result, you may download the sample input file uploaded on [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1cfpo538snnp352/NeuralNet_Inst0.pkl?dl=0). Please note that this program is written for this specific test and may not be generalizable.

```
import itertools
import pickle
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dropout
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from tensorflow import keras
import keras.backend as K

with open('NeuralNet_Inst0.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    result, sol = pickle.load(file)

# sol is the original input tensor
cZ1 = to_categorical(sol) # the converted input tensor

weight = result['weight'] # weights obtained by Keras
nNC = result['nNC'] # number of neurons in convolution layers
nNF = result['nNF'] # number of neurons in fully connected layers layers
layers = result['layers'] # dimension of layers
E = result['kSize'][0] # size of kernal
P = result['pSize'][0] # size of pool

actC = result['actC'] # activation function of convolution layers
actF = result['actF'] # activation function of fully connected layers

cRow = layers[0][0]
cCol = layers[0][1]

### Convolution Layers ###

cZ2 = np.zeros((cRow, cCol, nNC[0]), dtype=np.float32)
w2 = weight[0]
b2 = weight[1]

for n in range(nNC[0]):
    for t, m in itertools.product(range(cRow), range(cCol)):
        for npp, e, ep in itertools.product(range(cZ1.shape[2]), range(-1, E-1), range(-1, E-1)):
            if (t+e >= 0) and (m+ep >= 0) and (t+e <= cRow-1) and (m+ep <= cCol-1):
                cZ2[t, m, n] += w2[e+1, ep+1, npp, n] * cZ1[t+e, m+ep, npp]
    cZ2[:, :, n] += b2[n]

cZ2 = np.maximum(0, cZ2) # ReLU activation function

cZ3 = np.zeros((cRow, cCol, nNC[1]), dtype=np.float32)
w3 = weight[2]
b3 = weight[3]

for n in range(nNC[1]):
    for t, m in itertools.product(range(cRow), range(cCol)):
        for npp, e, ep in itertools.product(range(cZ2.shape[2]), range(-1, E-1), range(-1, E-1)):
            if (t+e >= 0) and (m+ep >= 0) and (t+e <= cRow-1) and (m+ep <= cCol-1):
                cZ3[t, m, n] += w3[e+1, ep+1, npp, n] * cZ2[t+e, m+ep, npp]
    cZ3[:, :, n] += b3[n]

cZ3 = np.maximum(cZ3, cZ3 * result['alpha']) # leaky ReLU activation function

### flattening layer ###    

fZ1 = np.zeros(layers[2][0] * layers[2][1] * layers[2][2], dtype=np.float32)
cnt1 = 0
cnt2 = 0
for t in range(layers[2][0]):
    for n in range(layers[2][2]):
        fZ1[cnt1] = np.max(cZ3[cnt2:cnt2 + P, :, n])
        cnt1 += 1
    cnt2 += P

### fully connected layers

fZ2 = np.zeros(nNF[0], dtype=np.float32)
w2 = weight[4]
b2 = weight[5]

for n in range(nNF[0]):
    for npp in range(w2.shape[0]):
        fZ2[n] += w2[npp, n] * fZ1[npp]
    fZ2[n] += b2[n]
fZ2 = np.maximum(fZ2, fZ2*result['alpha']) # leaky ReLU activation function

fZ3 = np.zeros(nNF[1], dtype=np.float32)
w3 = weight[6]
b3 = weight[7]

for n in range(nNF[1]):
    for npp in range(nNF[0]):
        fZ3[n] += w3[npp, n] * fZ2[npp]
    fZ3[n] += b3[n]
fZ3 = np.maximum(fZ3, fZ3*result['alpha']) # leaky ReLU activation function

fZ4 = 0
w4 = weight[8]
b4 = weight[9]

for npp in range(nNF[1]):
    fZ4 += w4[npp, 0] * fZ3[npp]
fZ4 += b4[0]
fZ4 = np.maximum(fZ4, fZ4*result['alpha']) # leaky ReLU activation function

print('My manual prediction is: ', fZ4)
print('The prediction of Keras is: ', 8.0)
print('The actual label of this data is: ', 0.6197)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to debug the above code by obtaining the [outputs of intermediate layers](https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer-feature-extraction) in Keras.
I replaced `nNF[1]` with `nNF[-2]` in **the last loop** and resolved the problem.